# How to write unit tests for server side Meteor code?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, backend

I have some server side code -- meteor methods and simple backend helpers -- that I would like to test. I've read the documentation testing with Meteor, but I am having a hard time connecting the documentation to my very simple use case. Can someone share with me how they've tested a meteor method or a simple backend JS function?

For instance, let's say you have some server method in, some_methods.js

```
function someHelper() {
// does lots of cool stuff
};

Meteor.methods({
  'user/update' (userProperties) {
     // updating some user properties
     someHelper();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

We have developed unit and integration tests for our open source application called RadGrad (https://radgrad.org).

For details on how we do unit and integration testing, please see:

https://www.radgrad.org/docs/developer-guide-testing.html

Here is an example of a unit (server-side only) test:

https://github.com/radgrad/radgrad/blob/master/app/imports/api/career/CareerGoalCollection.test.js

And here is an example of an integration (client + server) test:

https://github.com/radgrad/radgrad/blob/master/app/imports/api/career/CareerGoalCollection.methods.app-test.js

We do not have extensive UI tests; you'll need to use something like Selenium for that. UI testing in Meteor is no different from UI testing for any other web app.

Comment: Links in this answer are no longer active.

Comment: Broken links fixed.